# cache policy in php

Tags: php, mysql

i retrieve data from database which consists of images as well as other fields and then encode it in json format using php script.Now the data is 
being requested from phone what i want to do is to use cache policy or something else i.e if there is something in mysql might be, to check
whether the data is edited in database since last request or not so that when request comes to the page it will first check and then 
responed accordingly. which can save time, fast the request and also decrease the traffic on server.
i have read some notes about cache policy [here](http://www.chriskirkland.net/news/59_PHP-Cache-Control-script.html)

if some one help me along with example or code i shall be very thankful

Answer (score 2):

MySQL can't tell you when a record was last modified, but it's very simple to do it yourself: simply add a `timestamp` column to your tables in which you insert the current date and time each time you modify the record. MySQL can do this automatically by setting the initialization and update behaviors (see the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE t (
lastmodified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                       ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Then all you need to do is query that column along with your other data and check it against the `If-Modified-Since` header sent by the client. If the date and time in your result are more recent than those given by the client, you return the data as you normally would. Otherwise, simply send the `304 Not Modified` header without the content to let the client know nothing has changed since the last request.

Comment: http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/07/how-to-create-a-timestampdatetime-column-in-mysql-to-automatically-be-set-with-the-current-time/

Comment: sorry dude i did't get your point i would like to update the data on server everytime, the client just send request to that data so how the client would be know that data is updated. could you please explain this with example

Comment: my data is retrieved from three tables so in which table i put this timestamp

Comment: Add it to all three tables and check the most recent of the three against the timestamp sent by the client in the If-Modified-Since header.